# How can I use type arguments in an ltac?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to write the following function:

```
Ltac restore_dims :=
  repeat match goal with
  | [ |- context[@Mmult ?m ?n ?o ?A ?B]] => let Matrix m' n' := type of A in 
                                           let Matrix n'' o' := type of B in 
                                           replace m with m' by easy
         end.
```

That is, I want to use information  about the types of A and B  (which are both matrices with 2 dimension arguments) in my Ltac. Is that possible, and if so, how?

(Ideally, this would replace the `m` in question with `m'`  and likewise for `n` and `o` for all matrix products in my goal.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do syntactical matching on `type of A` to extract the arguments.

```
Ltac restore_dims :=
  repeat match goal with
  | [ |- context[@Mmult ?m ?n ?o ?A ?B]] =>
        match type of A with
        |  Matrix ?m' ?n' => replace m with m' by easy
        end;
        match type of B with
        |  Matrix ?n'' ?o' => replace n with n'' by easy
          (* or whatever you wanted to do with n'' and o' *)
        end
  end.
```

If you think `m` and `m'` will be convertible, not merely equal, and you care about having nice proof terms, consider using the tactic [`change`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.change) instead of `replace` e.g. `change n'' with n`. This won't add anything to the proof term, so it might be easier to work with.